# Google Map infoWindow - remove multiple after update content

Tags: dictionary, infowindow

i create da google map with multiple InfoWindow.
if i update infoWindow content, it's create new one.
so map always have new window
see image:[map infoWindow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgTBC.jpg)

code:

```
update()
update(){
markers[i].infoWindow = contents;
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[i].infoWindow);
            infoWindow.open( map, markers[i] );
}
```

I use time and call update function.
allways it gives new infoWindow

please help